# Move one element to first at DropdownList

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, struts2, drop-down-menu

I am listing townsForLanding for a city as like that:

```
<select id="townid" name="townid">
 <option selected="selected" value=""><s:text name="Choose One"/></option>
 <s:iterator value="townsForLanding">
  <option value="<s:property value="id"/>" <s:if test="id == townid">selected="selected" </s:if>>
  <s:property value="name"/></option>
 </s:iterator>
</select>
```

One of the name of a town is 'Central'. I get that list from database with struts2. I want the town with name 'Central' should be at the first(actually after 'Choose one') at drop-down-list.(Solution maybe with jQuery and JavaScript)

How can I do that?

Comment: Why not do it all on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example:

```
$('option:contains("Central")').insertAfter('select option:first-child');
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/x4bMa/

Comment: It's great. However I have a problem with this. If I have to dropdownlists, I want to do it just for one of them. How can I do this just for dropdownlist which has id of 'townid'?

Comment: This is with id selector: $('#townid option:contains("Central")').insertAfter('select option:first-child'); Thanks for your help Andy.